# Set down vs jot down vs make note

Tags: difference

I asked a native English friend of mine to write all the things she would say in one of her ordinary days, so that I could read them and learn some new useful expressions, but I hesitated whether I should have told her to "set down" or "jot down" or "make note" of them?

Comment: Have you looked up these words and phrases? If so, what conclusions have you drawn, and what questions do you have about them?

Comment: I feel that "make note" is usually used when you're for example on a class and the times that you want to remember something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Informal note-taking would be *jot down*.

> Let me **jot down** some ideas for you.

*make note* has to do with attention, not writing specifically. This is different from *make a note*.

> **Make note** of the following steps.

*set down* is used in formal contexts.

> The rules have been **set down** in writing so everyone can understand them.

I think *jot down* would be best in your context.